# How set react-select width depending on biggest option width?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, react-select

How set react-select input width depending on biggest option width? Options position is absolute and therefore their size not affect parent div width.

It is example: https://codesandbox.io/s/9o4rkklz14

I need to select width was longest option width.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I would recommend you to read this [guide for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us what you have already tried to resolve your problem.

Comment: I added minimal example.

Comment: But in your example is only one option with short input and longest value, what do You really want to do? In 'Selected Option' only label is displayed.

Comment: I need to autosize control depending on longest options. Now control expands on parent element width.

Answer (score -1):

I've answered this in a few issue threads [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2636) and [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2636) for more background about complexities and caveats, but here is the gist of the approach.

1. You need to set the width of the menu to be auto so it will stretch to fit its contents.
2. onMount, style the menu (height: 0, visibility: hidden) and open the menu with the internal ref method
3. With the onMenuOpen prop, use a function that waits 1ms, get the width of the listMenuRef, and close/reset the menuIsOpen.
4. With the calculated width, you can now set the width of the ValueContainer.

The result can be seen [here at this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-longest-option-width-geunu?file=/src/App.js)

Code posted below...

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const App = (props) => {
  const selectRef = useRef();

  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState();
  const [menuWidth, setMenuWidth] = useState();
  const [isCalculatingWidth, setIsCalculatingWidth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!menuWidth && !isCalculatingWidth) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsCalculatingWidth(true);
        // setIsOpen doesn't trigger onOpenMenu, so calling internal method
        selectRef.current.select.openMenu("first");
        setMenuIsOpen(true);
      }, 1);
    }
  }, [menuWidth, isCalculatingWidth]);

  const onMenuOpen = () => {
    if (!menuWidth && isCalculatingWidth) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const width = selectRef.current.select.menuListRef.getBoundingClientRect()
          .width;
        setMenuWidth(width);
        setIsCalculatingWidth(false);

        // setting isMenuOpen to undefined and closing menu
        selectRef.current.select.onMenuClose();
        setMenuIsOpen(undefined);
      }, 1);
    }
  };

  const styles = {
    menu: (css) => ({
      ...css,
      width: "auto",
      ...(isCalculatingWidth && { height: 0, visibility: "hidden" })
    }),
    control: (css) => ({ ...css, display: "inline-flex " }),
    valueContainer: (css) => ({
      ...css,
      ...(menuWidth && { width: menuWidth })
    })
  };

  const options = [
    { label: "Option 1", value: 1 },
    { label: "Option 2", value: 2 },
    { label: "Option 3 is a reallly realllly long boi", value: 3 }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <div> Width of menu is {menuWidth}</div>
      <Select
        ref={selectRef}
        onMenuOpen={onMenuOpen}
        options={options}
        styles={styles}
        menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: It is not working in the latest version 5.7.3. menuListRef is not getting.